# C# При динамическом добавлении кнопки в User Control ничего не происходит

Tags: c#, usercontrol

Вот код

```
public partial class  UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();       
    }

    public void ListFiles()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            Button b1 = new Button();
            b1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.ClientRectangle.Width / 2 - 125 / 2, this.ClientRectangle.Height / 2 - 32);
            b1.Size = new Size(125, 32);
            b1.TabIndex = 0;
            b1.Text = "TEXT";
            b1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            UserControl1 cont = new UserControl1();
            cont.Controls.Add(b1);                     
            y += 85;
        }
    }
}
```

Цикл проходит как надо, но ничего не рисуется в контроле. В чем проблема?
Если поместить код в UserControl(), то всё работает. Но мне нужно через отдельную функцию, чтобы только после определенных событий рисовало кнопку.

Comment: это уточнение к вопросу. добавьте в сам вопрос

Comment: @Андрей-nop, это же вроде winforms - почему метку wpf поставили?

Comment: @Сергей, кхм, разве? Автор, уточните, поставьте соответствующую метку

Comment: У wpf button даже свойств таких нет, попробуйте - все красным будет =)

Answer (score 0):

```
UserControl1 cont = new UserControl1(); //каждый раз создаете новый объект внутри своего объекта.
cont.Controls.Add(b1);
```

Попробуйте заменить эти две строки на это:

```
this.Controls.Add(b1);
```

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло.

Comment: А сам UserControl1 вообще где-нибудь в визуально дереве то помещается? Где и как он используется то

Comment: Конечно, помещается на форму. В контроле уже есть некоторые компоненты и они отображаются, но новые динамически добавить не выходит.

Comment: Не знаю, у меня все добавляется. Чего вы там наворотили - мне не известно